# Range of function $\frac{x^2}{1 + x^4}$?

Tags: functions

$$\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}$$

Dividing  numerator and denominator by $x^2$:-

$$\frac{1}{x^2+ \frac{1}{x^2}}$$

Applying AM GM, we get range as $[0, 1/2]$.

But if we are dividing by $x^2$, then the function should not attain value $0$ isn't it? Then is this method wrong?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Just apply derivatives to get maxima,minima

Comment: Just another way : Can you put $$ x^2=\tan y$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, good method!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not wrong if you use a little bit of care in your language. Say: for $x = 0$ we get the value $0$. For $x \ne 0$ ... then the rest of your argument; we get the range $(0,\frac 1 2]$. Now combine.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows, too:

Clearly the range is contained in the non-negative numbers, so pick $\;c\in\Bbb R_+\;$ :

$$\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}=c\iff cx^4-x^2+c=0$$

For the above biquadratic to have a real solution it must be that the discriminant is non-negative:

$$\Delta=1-4c^2\ge0\iff c^2\le\frac14\stackrel{\text{we know}\;c\ge0}\iff 0\le c\le\frac12$$